# Using Java ProcessBuilder in a Spring Batch Job - Tasklet

Tags: spring-batch, processbuilder, spring-batch-tasklet, spring-batch-job-monitoring

I am trying to execute terminal commands with arguments using Java ProcessBuilder. This code is written within a Java Spring Batch Tasklet that is executed as a part of a job.

Despite initializing it correctly using the below code, I receive a Null Pointer exception when the process builder tried to read my command arguments. This is strange and seems like there is some fundamental thing that I am missing.

Code that uses Process Builder

```
if (getActiveProfile().equals("test")) {
                        builder = new ProcessBuilder("somecommand",
                                "create", "-nr", "-c", configPath, "--tags", tags, name);
                    } else {
                        builder = new ProcessBuilder("somecommand",
                                "create", "-c", configPath, "--tags", tags, name);
                    }

                    Process p = builder.start();
```

This is where the error is being shown:

```
public Process start() throws IOException {
        // Must convert to array first -- a malicious user-supplied
        // list might try to circumvent the security check.
        String[] cmdarray = command.toArray(new String[command.size()]);
        cmdarray = cmdarray.clone();

        for (String arg : cmdarray)
            if (arg == null)
                throw new NullPointerException();
```

The above code snippet is from the ProcessBuilder class. Does anyone have any idea on what is going wrong?

Comment: please share the stack trace

Comment: Are you using the `SystemCommandTasklet` provided by Spring Batch or a custom tasklet?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Simple `Tasklet`

Comment: ok thanks so the error is not related to Spring Batch. According to the code you shared from ProcessBuilder: `if (arg == null) throw new NullPointerException();`, one of your args is null. Make sure `configPath`, `tags` and `name` are not null.